# Transform a lodash/underscore collection in a jQuery object (chaining)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I would like to seamlessly wrap a lodash collection in a jQuery object. Right now I'm saving the lodash output in a variable and feeding it to jQuery:

```
//simplified code
var els = [document.getElementById('a'), document.getElementById('b')];
els = _(els)
    .map(doStuff)
    .map(doMoreStuff);
var $els = $(els);
```

But I would like to chain it like this instead:

```
//pseudo code
_(els)
    .map(doStuff)
    .map(doMoreStuff)
    .jQueryfy() //this magic method, missing
    .show() //jQuery method, right away
```

I thought that it was possible with `tap`, but that doesn't actually change the collection.

```
_(els)
    .map(doStuff)
    .map(doMoreStuff)
    .tap(function(array) { return $(array); }) //doesn't actually return a jQuery object
    .show()
```

Comment: Are you trying to .show() all of the elements in the collection? You will probably have to use map or each to create your jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it by using [`mixin`](http://lodash.com/docs#mixin) with the [`jQuery` constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray) that does take an array of DOM elements:

```
_.mixin({jQueryfy: jQuery}, {chain:false});
```

Notice that jQuery itself does already support basic [collection manipulation functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/), so you could've written your example as well as

```
$("#a, #b").map(doStuff).map(doMoreStuff).show();
```

Comment: Super sweet! I knew that lodash had some one-liner like that. That was a simplified example, though, in reality those elements are being created from a collection. Either way lodash's loops are faster